# OSG +QT switching to full screen and back

Tags: qt, fullscreen, openscenegraph

I am integrating a single osgQt::GLWidget in a Qframe and using the pattern here: http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/browser/trunk/ossimPlanetQt/src/gui/ossimPlanetQtMainWindow.cpp to switch between full-screen mode and back. Basically consuming the keystrokes within the widget and setting full screen from there.

I also have an event consumer in osgViewer::Viewer - osgViewer::WindowSizeHandler which handles the viewer size switch.

Is there a better pattern to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you do (or, what is done in the example) seems fine. (Note that I am assuming that you refer to [`void ossimPlanetQtMainWindow::on_viewToggleFullScreen_triggered(bool )`](http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/browser/trunk/ossimPlanetQt/src/gui/ossimPlanetQtMainWindow.cpp#L889))

However, in the example, the QGLWidget `theGLWidget` is reparented between `tabWidget` and `theFullScreenFrame`. Under Windows, reparenting a `QGLWidget` will lead to a recreation of the QGLContext. (see [QGLWidget documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QGLWidget.html)

The workaround suggested by the docs is to wrap the GL widget in a dummy widget (a simple `QWidget`) and reparent that instead of the GL widget.

In my experience, this works fine.